# What is the best-practice way to share common files between Docker containers while maintaining portability?

Tags: php, docker-compose

I am fairly new to Docker and I'm wanting to create a set of containers using docker-compose for my PHP application.  The containers would be:

nginx
php-fpm
redis
worker

nginx, php-fpm and worker all need access to my application files (PHP and static content).  I know I can create a volume for the common files and share them between each of those containers, but I am set on the idea of making the application portable.  What I mean is, I would like to be able to easily build a new container and deploy it to a remote Docker host without having to worry about the shared volume on that remote host so that the app is all self-contained.

The only solution I see is to either create a single container and put nginx, php-fpm and the worker all in that one container and then copy the files into it OR just duplicate the file copies across all 3 containers.

I like the idea of having separate containers so that I could scale each if needed.  For example the worker container may need to be scaled into 2+ containers independent of the others.

What is the best-practice way to do this?  At the end of the day I am trying to create a deployment pipeline.  I have always just deployed code manually by pushing to Github and then going to the production server and pulling it down.  I want to live in world where I can push to Github and then trigger a pipeline to automatically build the updated container(s) and deploy them.

My thoughts are to use the Docker hub to host my container images and then use something like 'watchtower' to automatically swap out the containers when new container images are pushed to the Docker hub.

Looking for guidance on the best way to handle this without getting too complicated.

Answer (score -1):

Depending on your circumstances it might be best for you to setup a ftp server and integrate it with your application. That way you can access your files via ip address, local or foreign.

I found [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/delfer/alpine-ftp-server) ftp docker image which might come in handy.

Comment: Hahaha. Back to ftp like 1999?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).